# R $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

I have a dataset where one of the columns are only "#" sign. I used the following code to remove this column.

```
ia <- as.data.frame(sapply(ia,gsub,pattern="#",replacement=""))
```

However, after this operation, one of the integer column I had changed to factor.

I wonder what happened and how can i avoid that. Appreciate it.

Comment: What type of object is ia, pre- and post- sapply?

Comment: @Ironholds, i figured it was dataframe and after the operation, it became matrix. So I guess that was the reason. So I added as.data.frame. I have just edited my new question.

Comment: The reason it factored is, I suspect, because grep is for running over character strings, and stringsAsFactors is TRUE by default. In other words, to run gsub over it, you had to convert it to a character string on output, which then factored.

Comment: Yes and `sapply` will `simplify2array` and return a matrix. Use `lapply` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more correct version of your code might be something like this:

```
d <- data.frame(x = as.character(1:5),y = c("a","b","#","c","d"))
> d[] <- lapply(d,gsub,pattern = "#",replace = "")
> d
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3  
4 4 c
5 5 d
```

But as you'll note, this approach will never actually remove the offending column. It's just replacing the `#` values with empty character strings. To remove a column of all `#` you might do something like this:

```
d <- data.frame(x = as.character(1:5),
                y = c("a","b","#","c","d"),
                z = rep("#",5))
> d[,!sapply(d,function(x) all(x == "#"))]
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 #
4 4 c
5 5 d
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely if you want to remove an offending column from a data frame, and you know which column it is, you can just subset. So, if it's the first column:

```
df <- df[,-1]
```

If it's a later column, increment up.